# How to switch between two applications (Third-Party, like excel, chrome , etc) in python?

Tags: python

Well I am trying to build a program whose work is to run from one program(here chrome)copy it and paste it somewhere else(here excel). But I can't get it. Can I get it please?
Please help me with excel and chrome only...
Thanks in advance

Comment: If it chrome use requests to crawl the value that u want,If is excel  use panads or something else to write in?

Comment: `copy it and paste it` copy&paste *what*? Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to actually use Excel. You can use https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/ and https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/ to read and write from an xlsx file or use https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html for CSV files. Using chrome can be done through Selenium, or even generate a request using the requests module

Comment: No, I need my data in excel only.... And am I doing this becz it is not cool opening chrome, copying all data and paste it in excel every 5 minutes....